# Find duplicate column value in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite

I have inserted some values in the table `DataTab`.

```
SomeId: Integer     => Autogenerated primary key.
DataId: Guid
DataNumber: Integer
DataType: varchar
```

The above are the column's in my tables, I want to find, if the table contains repeated `DataId` values.
It has been a long time I had worked with databases. Now I can figure out simple queries. But I found this somewhat difficult.

I tried the following query, is this correct?

```
SELECT * from (Select * from DataTab) AS X 
where DataId= X.DataId AND SomeId!=X.SomeId
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
SELECT DataId, COUNT(*) c FROM DataTab GROUP BY DataId HAVING c > 1;
```

Comment: And if i want to check if DataId and DataNumber both are same for a record, then the query would be as follows, 

SELECT DataId, COUNT(*) c FROM DataTab GROUP BY DataId,DataNumber HAVING c > 1
,, Am i right?

Comment: SELECT DataId,DataNumber,COUNT(*) c FROM DataTab GROUP BY DataId,DataNumber HAVING c > 1. because whatever fields you'r taking in group by, it should be added in select statement.

Comment: Kindly upvote it as per stackoverflow guidelines if you found it is as per your expectation/ resolved your problem.

Comment: Thanks , Workes like a Charm ^^

Answer (score 3):

I have used it in my application. It is working based on your query

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM CENTERDETAILS a 
JOIN 
(SELECT IPADDR, MACID, COUNT(*) 
    FROM CENTERDETAILS  
    GROUP BY IPADDR, MACID 
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) b ON a.IPADDR = b.IPADDR OR a.MACID = b.mac 
ORDER BY a.MACID
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to convert what I read in the OP as the original approach into something that works and is fairly easy to remember compared to the combination of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM DataTab a 
JOIN DataTab b ON
  a.DataId = b.DataId
WHERE
  a.SomeId <> b.SomeId
```

Although it may be less efficient than [Jwalin Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980136/2932052).